# Is magnitude of cross product commutative?

Tags: forces, vectors, torque, mathematics

By definition of magnitude of cross product:

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|= \| \mathbf{F} \|\ \| \mathbf{r} \| \sin (\mathbf{F},\mathbf{r}) \tag1$

$\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|= \| \mathbf{r} \|\ \| \mathbf{F} \| \sin (\mathbf{r},\mathbf{F})\tag2$

By $(1)$ and $(2)$: $\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|=-\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|\tag3$

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|$ and $\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|$ are modes of vectors.

$\| \mathbf{F} \times \mathbf{r} \|$ and $\| \mathbf{r} \times \mathbf{F} \|$ are positive.

**Then how can equation $3$ be true?**

Comment: In (1) and (2) both, one takes the interior angle between $F$ and $r$ and hence the expressions are the same. Otherwise you'll have to take the absolute value.

Comment: The magnitude of a vector cannot be negative so if (3) were true both sides would have to equal zero.

Comment: @Nephente: should we take the mode of $\sin θ$?

Comment: I've never heard `mode` outside of statistics before, but yes, take the absolute value $|\sin|$.

Comment: There is no need (to take the absolute value of the sin), because the angle between the vectors is (by definition) smaller than $\pi$. Moreover the two expressions are the same.

Comment: The "commutativity" property applies to an operation, not to a value or variable. To ask if the result of an operation (or the magnitude of the result) is or not commutative does not make much sense anyway. Is the number 6 commutative? (6=2x3)

Answer (score 1):

We have 
\begin{align}
\vec a \times \vec b 
&= \sum_{i,j=1}^3 a_i b_j \vec e_k \epsilon_{ijk}
= -\sum_{i,j=1}^3 b_j a_i \vec e_k \epsilon_{jik}
= - \vec b \times \vec a
\end{align}
where in the second equation we used 
$
\epsilon_{ijk} = - \epsilon_{jik}
$. Taking the absolute value on both sides, we obtain 
$$
|\vec a \times \vec b|
= 
|\vec b \times \vec a|
$$
In conclusion: Yes, the magnitude of the cross product is commutative.